# How do I convert the below PHP code to VB.NET?

Tags: php, vb.net

How do I convert the below PHP code to VB.NET?

```
<?php
    $X_HOST ="foo.com";
    $X_URL = "/index.php";
    $X_PORT ="8080";
    $X_USERNAME = "foo";
    $X_PASSWORD = "bar";
    $s_POST_DATA = "Channel=UK.VODAFONE"; // Channel
    $s_POST_DATA .= "&Shortcode=12345"; // Shortcode
    $s_POST_DATA .= "&SourceReference=3456"; // Source Reference
    $s_POST_DATA .= "&MSISDN=447811111111"; // Phone
    $s_POST_DATA .= "&Content=test"; // Content
    $s_POST_DATA .= "&DataType=0"; // Data Type
    $s_POST_DATA .= "&Premium=1"; // Premium
    $s_POST_DATA .= "&CampaignID=4321"; // CampaignID
    $s_Request = "POST ".$X_URL." HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $s_Request .="Host: ".$X_HOST.":".$X_PORT."\r\n";
    $s_Request .="Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($X_USERNAME.":".$X_PASSWORD)."\r\n";
    $s_Request .="Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $s_Request .="Content-Length: ".strlen($s_POST_DATA)."\r\n";
    $s_Request .="\r\n".$s_POST_DATA;
    //Sends out the request to the server.
    $fp = fsockopen ($X_HOST, $X_PORT, $errno, $errstr, 30) or die("Error!!!");
    fputs ($fp, $s_Request);
    while (!feof($fp)) {
    $s_GatewayResponse .= fgets ($fp, 128);
    }
    fclose ($fp);
    //Array of official response codes.
    $a_Responses = array(
    "100" => "Server has returned an unspecified error.",
    "101" => "Server successfully received the request.",
    "102" => "Server has returned an database error",
    "103" => "Server has returned an syntax error."
    );
    echo "<HTML>\n<BODY>\n\n";
    //Checks for an official response code.
    foreach ($a_Responses as $s_ResponseCode => $s_ResponseDescription) {
    if (stristr($s_GatewayResponse, "\n$s_ResponseCode\n")) {
    echo "A response code of $s_ResponseCode was returned – ";
    echo $s_ResponseDescription";
    $b_CodeReturned = true;
    }
    }
    //Checks for an authorization failure where an official response code has 
    //not been recognized.
    if (!$b_CodeReturned) {
    if (stristr($s_GatewayResponse, "HTTP/1.1 401")) {
    echo "The server rejected your username/password (HTTP 401).";
    } else {
    echo "No recognised response code was returned by the server.";
    }
    }
    echo "\n\n</BODY>\n</HTML>";
    ?>
```

and

```
<?php
    $s_ref = $HTTP_POST_VARS["Reference"]; // Reference
    $s_trg = $HTTP_POST_VARS["Trigger"]; // trigger
    $s_shc = $HTTP_POST_VARS["Shortcode"]; // shortcode
    $s_pho = $HTTP_POST_VARS["MSISDN"]; // MSISDN
    $s_con = $HTTP_POST_VARS["Content"]; // Content
    $s_chn = $HTTP_POST_VARS["Channel"]; // Channel
    $s_pay = $HTTP_POST_VARS["DataType"]; // Data Type
    $s_dat = $HTTP_POST_VARS["DateReceived"]; // Date Received
    $s_cam = $HTTP_POST_VARS["CampaignID"]; // CampaignID
    $b_IsValid = getValidateRequest($s_ref, $s_trg, $s_shc, $s_pho, $s_con, $s_cam, $s_chn, $s_pay, 
    $s_dat);
    if ($b_IsValid) 
    {
    $s_ResponseCode = "success";
    } 
    else 
    {
    $s_ResponseCode = "fail";
    }
    exit($s_ResponseCode);
    /*******************************************************************************/
    function getValidateRequest ($s_req_ref, $s_req_trg, $s_req_shc, $s_req_pho, $s_req_con, $s_req_cam, 
    $s_req_chn, $s_req_pay, $s_req_dat) {
    /*
     * Stub function to be replaced with whatever process is needed to
     * process/validate request from server by specific client requirements.
     */
    return(true);
    }
    ?>
```

lastly

```
    <?php
$s_ref = $HTTP_POST_VARS["Reference"]; // Reference
$s_sta = $HTTP_POST_VARS["Status"]; // Status
$s_dat = $HTTP_POST_VARS["DateDelivered"]; // Date Delivered
$b_IsValid = getValidateReceipt($s_ref, $s_sta, $s_dat);
if ($b_IsValid) 
{
$s_ResponseCode = "success";
} 
else 
{
$s_ResponseCode = "fail";
}
exit($s_ResponseCode);
/*******************************************************************************/
function getValidateReceipt ($s_req_ref, $s_req_sta, $s_req_dat) 
{
/*
 * Stub function to be replaced with whatever process is needed to
 * process/validate receipts from server by specific client requirements.
 */
return(true);
}
?>
```

Thank you very much in advance
Regards
Greg

Comment: Nobody is going to write down large quantities of code for you. *What exactly* do you not understand?

Comment: The code is pretty simple to understand if you know any language...

Comment: Sorry, sorry, sorry, I get the point. (I mean -3 points)

Comment: +1 just b/c I feel sorry for you.  This is a very helpful community, you just have to show that you have done a little legwork on your own before you ask for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first bunch of code is just downloading a web page with specific headers & authentication. Check out the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class.

The other two chunks of code are just retreiving POST'd data from a client and then it passes those variables to the getValidateReceipt() function that validates what was sent in, note it's empty though, so it does nothing.

This looks like old PHP code as using the CURL library and $_POST would be more modern ways of doing things.

Answer (score 5):

Learn VB.NET and then start translating the code, carefully, line by line. It should be pretty straightforward.

If you don't know the equivalent of a PHP function in VB.NET, look it up or ask on SO.

Alternatively: Look / ask for VB.NET pre-made solutions that serve the same goal as your script.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479002.aspx) worked for me.

Its basically a comparison of common programming concepts in each language side by side with a running narrative.

I think this is the best way to LEARN how to convert PHP to vb.net